# Problems in starting a .ps1 script with the -NoNewWindow parameter

Tags: powershell

I have this powershell script where I simply set some DNS servers and interface metrics:

```
if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))  
{  
  $arguments = "& '" +$myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 4 -ResetServerAddresses
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 4 -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceMetric 10

Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 16 -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceMetric 5

Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 22 -ResetServerAddresses
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 22 -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceMetric 1
}
```

I run the script by right-clicking the .ps1 file and choosing Run with PowerShell and its working as expected.
However I would like to avoid the script opening a new powershell window but I'm having problem with -NoNewWindow parameter as I don't know exactly where to put it in this script.

If I do it like below, the script is not executing, I suppose its throwing errors but I dont see any output, it just open and closes itself immediately.

```
if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))  
{  
  $arguments = "& '" +$myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}
```

Comment: [Do not use `break` outside of a loop, `switch`, or `trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.3#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap). Use [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.3#exit) instead (causes PowerShell to exit a script).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your script is not running in Administrator mode,
and that's why `-NoNewWindow` is not working.
This parameter means that the started process is to run in the context
of the calling process and share its console window.

The problem is the argument `-Verb runAs`, which demands that the
started process is to run as Administrator. However, it's running
in the context of a non-admin script, so honoring it will mean
the elevation of your entire script to admin.

Windows does not permit any process to elevate itself.
A process is launched either as standard user or as administrator,
but once launched it cannot change its mode.

The two parameters are in conflict, which is why it fails.
You will need to continue running the script as it's now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the beginning of your script. You won't need admin for this or a commandline arg so it is easy to use when just running ps1's by clicking on them.

```
$nowindow = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);'
add-type -name win -member $nowindow -namespace native
[native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle, 0)
```

Comment: This is not working as expected, it still opens a new window. Most probably the reason is what @harrymc said in his answer.